# Is this possible to inject html code in utf-8 encoding to html page using thymeleaf and spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Recently I've decided to try to learn Thymeleaf with Spring MVC. And currently I'm storing html body fragments such as img, iframe etc. The problem has appeared after injecting this html fragments into one general html page using thymeleaf tags with UTF-8 encoding and cyrillic symbols. To be more precisely, these html fragments come in Model attribute from Spring controller. Is it possible to inject just the fragment into the one general html page such as below:

```html
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
<body>
[(${contents})] <!-- contents is that fragment I want to inject -->
</body>
</html>
```

Controller's request method is shown below:

```
    @GetMapping("/getArticle/{id}")
public String getArticle(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) throws IOException {
    Article article = articleService.getById(id);
    String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(article.getText())));
    model.addAttribute("contents", contents);
    return "news//article";
}
```

Content insert fragment example:

```html
<h1>Кириллица</h1>
<br/><iframe style='width: 30%; height: 35%;' src='link'></iframe><br/>
Классный видос, да?
```

[The result of combining 2 previous lists gives me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPRMc.png)

As I've previously mentioned, I've faced the trouble I have some curve symbols instead of russian ones. Also, I should note that, in case of normal page loading without injection, all the russian symbols are shown correctly. There's my ViewResolver and TemplateResolver from Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    thymeleafViewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    return thymeleafViewResolver;
}
```

So, the question is next: is this possible to directly inject html code which is received from the controller as an attribute using thymeleaf tags with correct UTF-8 encoding without curve symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you would at least need to change this line:

```
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(article.getText())));
```

to this:

```
String contents = Files.readString(Paths.get(article.getText()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This uses the `readString()` method with a `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8` character set. Otherwise, your bytes from `readAllBytes()` are being written to a string in what could be some other (non-UTF-8) encoding - probably depending on the default character set picked up by the JVM when it started.

However, for learning Thymeleaf, I would recommend looking into Thymeleaf [fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#fragments) (if you have not already done so), since these are designed for this purpose.

This will then lead you into [template layouts](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#template-layout), which have a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was I hadn't set up UTF-8 encoding during reading the file. Probably, I should try to debug the application, but I'm lazy bone a bit and thought there had been some problems with the template view, but not with my Java code. Also, thank you for advice to learn the thymeleaf layouts and fragments, I obviously must learn it)